# Actionscript 3.0 Keyboard Controlled Walking Character

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to flash and actionscript, but I wanted to try to begin with something simple.

I have a character with a stationary stance, a right walking motion, and a left walking motion.

Basically I want it so that when the player hits the right arrow key, the character will move right and go to frame 2 to play the walking right animation. Same with walking left.

My setup is:
Inside Main Character Movie Clip-

Frame 1.) Stationary

Frame 2.) Right walking animation

Frame 3.) Left walking animation

If someone could help it would be greatly, greatly appreciated.
Also, if someone does decide to help, could you give me some code that feels fluent and playable? You know, with momentum?

Comment: Have you tried searching google? The first result I clicked would be a perfect starting point. If you run into trouble come back with a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that:

```
stage.focus = character;

character.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, characterMoving);
character.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, characterStopping);

function characterMoving(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    switch (key) {
        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            character.gotoAndStop(2);
            break;
        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            character.gotoAndStop(3);
            break;

    }
}

function characterStopping(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    character.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

If you want your character to jump, you can apply [the code I've left here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246962/as3-smooth-jumping/25250053#25250053).

Comment: Not to annoy you or make myself sound like more of an idiot, but where do I put the script? Do I put it in a blank keyframe inside of the Character's movieclip, or on the timeline outside of it? Or somewhere else completely?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Anthony Marcello Zucchero - On the timeline. You should learn the code if you want to create a game.